# Collect the data from both Nested List and Outer List with Java Streams

Tags: java, list, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

```
Class Package{
  Long packageId;
  String packageName;
  List<Service> serviceList;
}

Class Service{
  Long serviceId;
  String location;
}

List <Package> packageList
```

Above there are my classes and the requirement is to collect `packageId` from the outer list `packageList` and `serviceId` from the inner list (the `Services` of each `Package`) where `packageList.packageName == "Full"` and `serviceList.location == "Japan"`. Also, I need to know whether that kind of record exist or not. This is what I've written so far collecting the data into a `HashMap`.

```
HashMap<String,Object> stringObjectHashMap = new HashMap<>();
boolean isFound = packageList.stream()
                .filter(package -> "Full".equalsIgnoreCase(package.getPackageName()))
                .peek(package ->stringObjectHashMap.put("packageId",package.getPackageId()))
                .flatMap(package -> package.getServiceList().stream())
                .filter(service -> service.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("Japan"))
                .peek(service -> stringObjectHashMap.put("serviceId",service.getServiceId()))
                .anyMatch(service -> service.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("Japan"));
```

The problem is that Sonar complains about the use of `peek()` inside the stream. It says "*According to its JavaDocs, the intermediate Stream operation java.util.Stream.peek() “exists mainly to support debugging” purposes.*"

Can anyone suggest a better solution?

sample input:

```
[
    {
        "packageId": 13,
        "packageName": "Normal",
        "serviceList": [
            {
                "serviceId": "100",
                "location": "China"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "packageId": 10,
        "packageName": "Full",
        "serviceList": [
            {
                "serviceId": "100",
                "location": "Spain"
            }
        ]
    },
     {
        "packageId": 5,
        "packageName": "Full",
        "serviceList": [
            {
                "serviceId": "100",
                "location": "Japan"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

expected output,

```
"packageId": 5    //this is from outer list
"serviceId": 100  //this is from inner list
```

***Note:*** `"Full"` *package* can appear multiple times. As well as location `"Japan"` also can appear multiple times in services. But a combination of the `packageName` with a value `"Full"` and location `"Japan"` can appear only once.

Comment: No problem. I can use as HashMap<String,Long> stringObjectHashMap = new HashMap<>();

Comment: Please provide a sample input and the desired output. It is not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve. By the way, are you aware that you will constantly overwrite your map if there are multiple services that have the location `Japan` ?

Comment: As I understand your code, you're creating a map that would contain `2` entries at most (*is it international?*). What should be the result when there's a package with a name `"Full"`, but no service with location `"Japan"` - an empty map, map with one entry?

Comment: sample json and output attached

Comment: What if there exist a package with a `packageName = Full` and multiple services having `location = Japan` ? Which one do you want to keep? The first, the last or a list of all? Or is it garanteed that there is only one service in the list?

Comment: *sample json and output attached* - but it doesn't cavers edge-cases: *no service* with location `"Japan"`, *multiple services* with location `"Japan"`. What should be the result with such a data?

Comment: in that case I can take first one. because in the real scenario there is only one record which having "packageName": "Full" and "location": "Japan".

Comment: So, in the case of valid data "full" package is always present (it always only one), and it expected to contain a single service having location "Japan"?

Comment: "full" package can appear multiple time. location "Japan" also can appear multiple time in services. but packageName with "full" and location "Japan" combination can happens only once.

Answer (score 3):

By using `.flatMap(package -> package.getServiceList().stream())` you actually bring all the services for all the packages into one huge stream and get everything mixed up.

If I understand the task correctly, you want to select all packages with name "Full", and then, for each such package, select any service in that package's list with location "Japan", or null, if such service is not there. You can just `collect` to such a map like this:

```
Map<String,Long> stringObjectMap = packageList.stream().filter(p -> "Full".equalsIgnoreCase(p.getPackageName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Package::getPackageId,
                    p -> p.getServiceList().stream()
                            .filter(service -> "Japan".equalsIgnoreCase(service.getLocation()))
                            .map(Service::getServiceId)
                            .findFirst().orElse(null) //you might want to use a stand-in default value here instead of null
            ));
```

Note: this will result in some obscure implementation of Map, not really a HashMap, so you might need to make adjustments.

Personally, I find such cases more easily solvable by using regular for-loops.

Comment: Yeah I like this solution, the use of `Collectors#toMap` on the package id is a great idea. Much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is filter through each of the packages to find all full packages, then perform a reduction on those packages to find services that are from japan.

```java
        List<Package> fullPackages = packageList
                .stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getPackageName().equals("Full"))
                .toList();

        List<Service> fromJapan = fullPackages
                .stream()
                .flatMap(p -> p.getServiceList().stream())
                .filter(service -> service.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("Japan"))
                .toList();
```

Also, from what it looks like, the key is not unique, so it's going to continue to get overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 12 or above, you could achieve your goal by using the `teeing` operation to create a first downstream of `Packages` and a second downstream of `Services`. Both of them would return a `Map<String, Long>` containing the fixed `Strings` with the expected ids. Also, if you need to know if the record has been found you could check the number of entries of your returned `Map`.

```
Map<String, Long> mapRes = packageList.stream()
        .filter(pack -> pack.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase("Full") && pack.getServiceList().stream().anyMatch(s -> s.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("Japan")))
        .collect(Collectors.teeing(
                Collectors.toMap(p -> "packageId", Package::getPackageId, (id1, id2) -> id1),
                Collectors.flatMapping(pack -> pack.getServiceList().stream(), Collectors.toMap(s -> "serviceId", Service::getServiceId, (id1, id2) -> id1)),
                (map1, map2) -> {
                    map1.putAll(map2);
                    return map1;
                }));

boolean isFound = mapRes.entrySet().size() == 2;
```

Alternatively, if Sonar is signaling you the abuse of the `peek` operation and you still want to employ stateful lambdas although not advisable, then you could replace each `peek` with a `map` doing the exact operations and then returning the given element. This is your original code with the `peek` replaced by `map`.

```
boolean isFound = packageList.stream()
        .filter(pack -> "Full".equalsIgnoreCase(pack.getPackageName()))
        .map(pack -> {
            stringObjectHashMap.put("packageId", pack.getPackageId());
            return pack;
        })
        .flatMap(pack -> pack.getServiceList().stream())
        .filter(service -> service.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("Japan"))
        .map(service -> {
            stringObjectHashMap.put("serviceId", service.getServiceId());
            return service;
        })
        .anyMatch(service -> service.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("Japan"));
```

Here there is also a link to test the code:

https://ideone.com/uV5PIQ

Comment: *Sonar is signaling you the abuse of the `peek` operation, then you could simply replace it with a `map`* - Basically, instead of abusing `peek()` you're advising to misuse `map()` by making use of stateful functions. Doesn't look like a good alternative.

Comment: I'm advising to use the teeing approach. After seeing her/his code with peek, I didn't really think stateful lambda were the biggest concern. The map approach was just a workaround. **My solution** involves using teeing. They're not placed in that order for no reason.

Comment: Dan, there are no issues with the code that utilizes `Collectors.teeing()` apart from the fact that it has to process the target list of services twice. I was talking about the solution that updates the resulting map via  `map()` operation. The original version with `peek()` is more readable because it doesn't require multiline expressions with an explicit `return` statement. If you are certain that `map()` will mute the Sonar's complaints... well, I've already told my opinion on that.

Comment: I think there's been a misunderstanding. I know which one of the two solutions you're talking about., but it sounded as if the map approach was my only solution. I've placed them in that order because I consider the teeing approach the right one. Using map like that was just a second offer/workaround to a code that already contained stateful lambdas. That made me think that having stateful lambdas wasn't probably their biggest concern.

Answer (score 1):

#### Stream-based solution

Assuming that `packageName` with value of `"Full"` and a *service* `location` equal to `"Japan"` and every `packageId` is unique, we can create an intermediate map by mapping an *optional of service* (service located in Japan) to a `packageId` and generate a final result based on it.

```
Map<String, Long> ids = packageList.stream()
    .filter(pack -> "Full".equalsIgnoreCase(pack.getPackageName()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap( // Map<Long, Optional<Service>> - intermediate map
        Package::getPackageId,
        pack -> pack.getServiceList().stream()
            .filter(service -> service.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("Japan"))
            .findFirst()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().isPresent())
    .findFirst()
    .map(entry -> Map.of("packageId", entry.getKey(), 
                "serviceId", entry.getValue().get().getServiceId()))
    .orElse(Collections.emptyMap());
```

Can we do better? We can, currently, solution processes all the data which is not needed in case when the target *package & service* were found.

We can make the solution short-circuit by using `findFirst()` operation, which will also avoid double-checking (*iterate over a list of services twice*).

And it actually would be much more handy to use a simple *DTO*, for instance a Java 16 *record* with two attributes, rather than a map. But because your existing code depends on a map as a result I'll continue with map, and internally as an intermediate mean of string data I'll use `Map.Entry`.

```
Map<String, Long> ids = packageList.stream()
    .filter(pack -> "Full".equalsIgnoreCase(pack.getPackageName()))
    .map(pack -> Map.entry(pack.getPackageId(), pack.getServiceList().stream()
        .filter(service -> service.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("Japan"))
        .findFirst()))
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().isPresent())
    .findFirst()   // <- will produce an intermediate result as Optional<Map.Entry<Long, <Optional<Service>>>
    .map(entry -> Map.of("packageId", entry.getKey(), 
                "serviceId", entry.getValue().get().getServiceId()))
    .orElse(Collections.emptyMap());
```

This version is more performant. It'll terminate the stream execution when the combination of `"Full"` *package* with a *service* located in `"Japan"` will be encountered, instead of processing all data set.

It's much better now, but one issue we can't resolve - it is not possible to eliminate the nested stream (because we need to iterate over the list of services) which spoils the readability.

*Reminder:* streams were introduces in Java as a mean of structuring the code in a simple well-readable way, not the opposite. Old plain loops perform better than sequential streams.

#### Imperative solution

Now let's implement the same logic using an imperative approach.

```
Map<String, Long> result = new HashMap<>();

for (Package pack: packageList) {
    if (!pack.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase("Full")) continue;
            
    for (Service service: pack.getServiceList()) {
        if (service.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("Japan")) {
            result.put("packageId", pack.getPackageId());
            result.put("serviceId", service.getServiceId());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Conditional logic is much easier to implement using plain loops. Very concise, easy to read, easy to maintain.

And as a result, imperative solution is not only much cleaner, but also more performant because doesn't require entails unnecessary actions: map will be updated only once.

You can also compare it with your initial approach that uses side effects via `peek()` which continuously updates the map.